# possible strategies to solve a complicated complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

During some computations have come across this formidable looking integral

$$\int_{\mathcal{D}}dz\,e^{-z/a}\frac{1}{(1-nz)^{1+b}}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}c_r(1-nz)^r$$

where $a$, $n$, $b$ and all the $c_r$ are real ($a$ and $b$ positive) and $z$ is a complex variable and  the integration is performed on the line $\epsilon{}e^{i\phi}$ at the point $z=1/n$ for $\phi$ running from $\pi$ to $0$. I would be very glad if anybody could give me any hint that might work.

Comment: What does "on the line $\epsilon e^{i\phi}$ at the point $z=1/n$" mean?

Comment: Is $b$ an integer? Positive real?

Comment: @Joel b real and positive. I will edit